# OnePageNav adding Link outside the menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the One Page Navigation Plugin which allows for one menu to control the whole site.

Now I'd like to add a link outside of that menu to link to home also using the scroll effect the scripts provide.

- [jQuery One Page Nav Plugin](http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav)

Also using ScrollTo and LocalScroll.

The menu:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="current rotmin"><a href="#one">Home</a></li>
  <li class="space">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="rotplus"><a href="#two" class="menuitem">About</a></li>
  <li class="space">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="rotmin"><a href="#three" class="menuitem">Blog</a></li>
  <li class="space">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="rotplus"><a href="#four" class="menuitem">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The code:

```
$('#nav').onePageNav({
  currentClass: 'current',
  changeHash: false,
  scrollSpeed: 1000
});
```

Someone who can do a better job with the title, please feel free to change it as it's very unclear, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a item after/outside the `#nav`

You have tried it with [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$('<a href="#home">Test</a>').insertAfter('#nav');
```

You also can do it with [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

After that add something thats unset the functionality of the *one page navigation*.

Comment: Ah... sorry, I'm being stupid! I could just use ScrollTo for the link outside the menu... duh! As you're here first I'll give you the correct answer =) Thanks though!